# NoClassDefFoundError when loading servlet filter from jar

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, noclassdeffounderror, servlet-filters

I created [a servlet filter](https://github.com/Realiserad/servlet-logging-filter) which I'm trying to use in WildFly 26 with an application deployed as an EAR file, so I added this to the `web.xml` file:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.stormhub.jakarta.LoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The servlet filter resides in the `org.stormhub.jakarta` package and implements the `jakarta.servlet.Filter` interface.

This is what the deployed EAR file looks like:

```
some.ear
|
|-- some.war
    |
    |-- WEB-INF/
        |
        |-- lib/
            |
            |-- servlet-logging-filter-1.0.0.jar
```

The `servlet-logging-filter-1.0.0.jar` file looks like this:

```
org
|
|-- stormhub
    |
    |-- jakarta
        |
        |-- LoggingFilter.class
```

When starting WildFly it prints the error message:

```
Failed to define class org.stormhub.jakarta.LoggingFilter 
in Module "deployment.some.ear.some.war" 
from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Failed to link org/stormhub/jakarta/LoggingFilter 
(Module "deployment.some.ear.some.war" from Service Module Loader): 
jakarta/servlet/Filter
```

Why is the class loader not finding my servlet filter?

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins WildFly 26 as stated in the post. :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I saw that then glanced over it. You’d need to use WildFly Preview or preferably WildFly 27 if you want to use Jakarta EE 10 API’s.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins You're correct. I considered sending this to the WildFly mailing list, but I misinterpreted the error and thought it had something to do with how the war file was built.

If you provide your response as an answer in this thread, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WildFy 26 is a [Jakarta EE 8](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/). WildFly 26 Preview is a [Jakarta EE 9.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9.1/) container and WildFly 27 is a [Jakarta EE 10](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/) container. If you want to use Jakarta EE 9+, `jakarta` namespaced API's, you need to use WildFly 26 Preview or better yet WildFly 27.